# Definition of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The derivative of a function is defined by
$$
f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}{\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}}
$$
provided the limit exists. For example for $f(x)=\sin(x)$ we can prove that (see [here](http://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/calculus/derivative_proofs/sinx))
$$
f^{\prime}(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}{\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}}=\cos(x)
$$
But for integration there are only a set of formulas that come from the above definition (i.e. with knowing the derivative of a function). Is there a general definition for integration like above definition (maybe an anti-limit!) that acts on a function directly?

Comment: @user35603: I'm sure the OP know about that already since it will be on the first page or so on any books on integration. OP is probably asking about antiderivative, rather than integration.

Comment: My question is about indefinite integral.

Comment: [$F(x)=D^{-1}f(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#The_derivative_as_a_function)

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

I don't think there can be a general definition for an indefinite integral. Here's why:

Let us say that we are trying to find this integral:

$$\int_\ sinx$$

This would equal $$-\cos(x) + C$$

Now, given any constant $C$, no matter what we are always going to achieve the same derivative  for a function $f(x)$.

However, for any constant $C$, we will achieve different answers when we find the antiderivative.

This is why integration cannot be expressed in a closed, general equation. **Constants aren't negligible.**